# Simple Javascript for set multiple variables

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a Javascript way how to simple set multiple variables like in PHP?

example in PHP:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'first code or text';
$var2 = 'second code or text';
...
?>
```

and called enywhere simply by

`<?php echo $var1; ?>`

I founded for Javascript only "innerHTML" approach, associated with elements/id tags

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('variable1');
el.innerHTML = 'taste text';
</script>
```

with

```
<span id="variable1"></span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to do that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var var1="first code or text";
var var2="second code or test";
</script>
```

Then you display it on your page by document.write() function which is in the core of javascript you have to call it at the place you want like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(var1);
</script>
```

Comment: sadly cant be directly inserted into html code like php... <a href="http://"><script>document.write(var1);</script></a>